# Solr block join child field with expand gets error

Tags: search, solr, lucene

I used solr's nested document support to index my documents. I tried to query both parent and children at the same time. My query is q={!parent which="parent_field"} child_field&wt=json&indent=true&expand=true&expand.field=*root*&expand.q=*:*
However, some times on particular field I receive the following error:

child query must only match non-parent docs, but parent docID=2147483647 matched childScorer=class org.apache.lucene.search.TermScorer

This error seems to randomly happen. What caused this error? Is there an example of how to filter document by both parent and children using solr?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Block join is used to either 
a. retrieve parent based on child field match, or 
b. retrieve all child docs for a parent match
but not both. Your query looks like you want to fetch parent documents with child field match. However, have you given "condition match for child_field"? I am not able to see it. 
documentation [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Other+Parsers#OtherParsers-BlockJoinQueryParsers)

Comment: Hi nice to see you again. My basic idea is to retrieve document by matching terms in both parent and children. For example, suppose parent document is a song, and child is a user comment. If you want to find a song which genre is rock (parent field) and has most "like" in the comment (child field) how would you construct the query?

Comment: It seems that this error happens when a field has a unique value and only one parent document was retrieved. This seems to be some bug I hope it can be resolved in the future

Comment: **q={!parent which="genre:rock"}comments:like**. This should fetch you the sond document. And only one parent document retrieval is a regular use case. So no error should be throw. It is always possible to have only one child.